# Google Scripts: cannot convert range to (class) error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting this error:
"Cannot convert range to (class) on this line:

```
var cellFrom = ss.getRange(rowFrom, i).getCell(1,1);
```

This is the function:

```
function copyValidations(sheetName, rowFrom, rowTo, column, numColumns) {
 /* Copy validations of all cells in rowFrom to cells in rowTo, starting at column.\*/

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  for (var i = column;i<= column + numColumns;i++) {
    var cellFrom = ss.getRange(rowFrom, i).getCell(1,1);
    var cellTo = ss.getRange(rowTo, i).getCell(1,1);
    copyCellDataValidation(cellFrom, cellTo); 
  }
}
```

I need to pass ranges of single cells to copyCellDataValidation:

```
function copyCellDataValidation(cellFrom, cellTo) {
 /* Copies the data validation rules and data from a single cell to another cell
*/

  var rule = cellFrom.getDataValidation();
  if (rule != null) {
   var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
   var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
   cellTo.setDataValidation(rule.copy().withCriteria(criteria, args).build());
  } else {
   //Logger.log('copyCellDataValidation: The cell does not have a data-validation rule.')
  }
}
```

I only found suggestions to fix this error when setValues() was involved, but nothing to help me here.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem.

I was passing a range object instead of integer to the function.
Here it is working:

```
function copyValidations(sheetName, rowFrom, rowTo, column, numColumns) {
 /* Copy validations of all cells in rowFrom to cells in rowTo, starting at column.\*/

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  for (var i = column;i<= column + numColumns;i++) {
    var cellFrom = ss.getRange(rowFrom, i);
    var cellTo = ss.getRange(rowTo, i);
    copyCellDataValidation(cellFrom, cellTo); 
  }
}
```